# How to get the updated list

Tags: java, list

I have written a method to update a collection in a class. It looks like :

```
public List<Queue> updateCollection(List<Queue> queueList,int indexid,Queue s) {
    for(Queue queue : queueList) {
        queueList.set(indexid, (Queue) s);
    }
    System.out.println(queueList);
    return queueList;
}
```

Now I am making updates by calling the above method. But the updated list is not getting reflected in the main method. Can someone please help?

Comment: How is `updateCollection()` being called in the main method?

Comment: You should post a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org)

Comment: queueList =selection.updateCollection(queueList, j, s); where j is the index and s is the update that I am trying to make.

Comment: Why are you looping through your list?

Comment: I am going through the list and once I find the index of 'j' I make the update at that position.

Comment: @user2988935 that is definitely not what's happening here. You're going to need an if-statement for that.

Comment: @user2988935: No, you are setting the element at index `indexid` once for each element in your list, which doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is in call `queueList.set(indexid, (Queue) s);` in loop. The variable `indexid` is not being changed during looping. This means that you always put all your elements to the same position. If for example `indexid` is 0 you set all your element to 0 position, so at the end of iteration the last element will  be there and all other will be lost.

if you want to copy elements from queue to list use `eiter queuList.add(s)` in loop or `queueList.addAll(s)`.

Comment: The value is already there in the list. I already have the value of("QUEUE_1","QUEUE_2",true) in the list 2nd position. Now I want to update that to ("QUEUE_1","QUEUE_2",false)

Answer (score 0):

Your loop iterates over the `Queue`s in `queueList` but does nothing with `queue`. I just sets the `indexid`th item in the list to `s` repeatedly. This would be the same as:

```
for(int i = 0; i < queueList.size; ++i) {
    queueList.set(indexid, (Queue) s);
}
```

Comment: I am able to see the updated list in the method. When i get the updated list, I still see the old one :-(.

Answer (score 0):

it's iterating through the collection but change nothing. Use it instead of loop.

```
if (indexid >=0 && indexid < queueList.size())
  queueList.set(indexid, (Queue) s);
```